# Qualitative explanation of the high open-loop gain of a 741 op-amp using its internal circuit characteristics

Tags: loop-gain, 741-opamp

Here is the internal circuit of a 741 op-amp:

[image]

Using small signal analysis, I can claim the open loop voltage gain to be the product of the current gain of the transistors in the Darlington pair(Q15, Q19) and those in the input circuit emitter followers(Q1, Q2).

This should not include the output push-pull amplifier stage (Q14, Q20), as it has no voltage gain.

This can give me somewhere near the order of 10E+8, thus nearing infinity, as it should be for an ideal op-amp.  When I looked up the characteristics of the 741 op-amp, it shows an open-loop gain of around \$2 \times 10^{5}\$.

Is there any way to understand this deviation qualitatively, or does one have to do the simulations and calculations to understand in this case? Does this occur due to the frequency response of the circuit? I would like to observe this qualitatively at first, before going into the simulations and the extensive calculations, in order to carry an intuition before actually testing it out. Can someone help me out in this?

Comment: You are asking for opinions about whether your explanation is "qualitative enough". Enough for what purpose? Why are you bothering to analyze this old circuit at all?

Comment: How exactly does one quantify qualitativeness?

Comment: Yeah, it's an old circuit, but before starting with the simulations, I was asked to analyze the internal circuit of the 741 Op-Amp, that's why.

Comment: I'm still a novice, but I believe that qualitativeness would probably refer to analyzing the circuit top to bottom, left to right, and come up with an explanation without making use of actual calculations, which would mean quantitative.

Comment: Quote: "I can claim the open loop voltage gain to be the product of the current gain of the transistors in the Darlington pair". No - you cannot. How can a voltage gain "be the product of current gains"?

Comment: What do you mean by "I was asked to analyze..."? Is this some kind of homework or school assignment?

Answer (score 2):

You have two principal gain blocks, the input differential to single-ended amplifier around Q1, and the amplifier around Q15.

Both of those amplifiers involve output loads which are ideally infinite, but whose impedance will be brought down by real transistor effects like finite output impedance of the Q4/6 current source.

What you're being asked to do is to get an understanding of how the circuit works, so that when you make the (inevitable) mistake or three doing detailed calculations, you have a better chance of debugging where you went wrong, and indeed spotting that it's wrong in the first place.

Both figures of 10<sup>8</sup> (how did you arrive at that?)(show your working and we can advise better) and 2x10<sup>5</sup> are 'big', so you could be in the right ballpark. If the difference is real transistor effects, so lower h<sub>fe</sub> and h<sub>oe</sub> than you expect, then you're there, because there are lots of them and they would all multiply up.

Don't neglect the loading that the darlington stage puts on the first stage. You need to examine this stage carefully to see what its input impedance and gain are. Don't neglect the input impedance of the output stage on its gain either.

If you could walk us through how you arrived at 10<sup>8</sup>, then we could give you a better critique.

Comment: So, assuming the current gains of the transistors to be around 100, and the fact that the Darlington amplifier acts an active load for the current mirror Q12, Q13, turns the current gain into a voltage gain, around the order of 10E4. Similar considerations around Q1, Q2 would give a voltage gain around 10E4, and the net open-loop gain would be around 10E8 probably, the product of those 2. But, 2*10E5 is the gain which I noticed on looking up 741's datasheet, not something which I calculated, so I don't seem to understand where I am going wrong actually.

Comment: @electrovolt Yes, that's the right sort of hand-waving. Put it into your original question, starting from the input emitter followers onwards, with a little more exposition. I suspect the largest error you've made is not considering the input impedance of Q15 et al reducing the gain of the first stage.